# Bash script will not run properly using a hotkey, runs fine from a terminal emulator

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and I'm having issues with a bash script I wrote to switch between my screens. It uses `xrandr` commands with `grep` to find out which screen is enabled at runtime, and depending on the output of that command it switches to either of the screens that were disabled using `xrandr` again. Also some `pacmd` commands to switch the default audio output from the HDMI audio to the pci soundcard of this computer, and then move all the pulseaudio sinks to the new output.

My problem is that this script runs fine with I run it using any terminal emulator, but when I run it with a hotkey set in `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom`, it always fails to run fully and it botches my screen settings (it mirrors all of them!).

I've been over this for quite a while but I can't figure it out on my own. I even switched between different distros thinking it could be an xorg bug but I just can't get it to work.

I'm pasting the code of my script in hopes that I can get some help.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

SINK_ID=$(pactl list sink-inputs | sed -n 's/^Sink Input #\([0-9]*\)$/\1/p') # this line grabs all the pulseaudio sink inputs

function RunHDMIScreen { #function to change DPI and switch from monitors to HDMI TV
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.55
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DVI-I-1 --off --output DVI-I-0 --off --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --off
pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo"
pactl move-sink-input $SINK_ID "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo"
}

function RunMonitors { #function to disable the HDMI TV and switch to monitors
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x2 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --off --output DVI-I-1 --off --output DVI-I-0 --mode 1024x768 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --off
pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_03_07.0.analog-stereo"
pactl move-sink-input $SINK_ID "alsa_output.pci-0000_03_07.0.analog-stereo"
}

function HDMIConnected {
   xrandr | grep "HDMI-0" | grep "primary" #this line checks if the HDMI screen is running, i presume this one is the failing one but I don't know of any other way to check the currently active display
}

if HDMIConnected
then
RunMonitors
else
RunHDMIScreen
exit
fi
```

Comment: First thing I would do in a situation like this is put some diagnostic `echo` statements into the script and redirect them to a log file (along with the standard error stream)

Comment: How should I do that in this example?

Comment: any help with this please?

Comment: I test for a specific monitor to be enabled with `xrandr | grep -q "DP2 connected ("`, where `DP2` is `xrandr`'s output name. To troubleshoot please redirect the script's output to a logfile by making your hotkey command e.g. `bash /path/to/script >>~/random_log_name`, then press the hotkey and [add here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1019403/edit) what gets written to the file.